# Rails/React app: ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have a React and Rails app that I recently updated from node 12->16 and Rails 5->6, and as a part of that process webpack 3->4. I've been getting the following error when running `yarn start` to get my dev server running. Running `./bin/webpack-dev-server` does not yield any errors.

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/nicolascarroll/nomad_2_app'
```

My app's entry point is `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`, so not sure why it is looking for `src/index.js`

I've been scouring similar threads on Stackoverflow to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Error

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/nicolascarroll/nomad_2_app'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/nicolascarroll/nomad_2_app'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src main[2]
```

package.json

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.19.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  },
  "jestWebpackResolver": {
    "webpackConfig": "./config/webpack/test.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "resolver": "jest-webpack-resolver",
    "testRegex": "_spec.js$"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "16": "^0.0.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.15",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^1.0.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-upgrade": "^1.0.1",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "coffee-script": "^1.12.6",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "core-js": "3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.8.4",
    "jstimezonedetect": "^1.0.6",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "node": "^18.13.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "path-complete-extname": "^0.1.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss-smart-import": "^0.7.4",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "random-material-color": "^1.0.5",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^11.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "2.10.1",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-intl-tel-input": "^8.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^7.1.0",
    "react-timeago": "^4.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "1.x",
    "react_ujs": "^2.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "strftime": "^0.10.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.15",
    "timepicker": "^1.11.12",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "yarn-add-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.13.15",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "jest-webpack-resolver": "^0.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

config/webpack/configuration.js

```
const { join, resolve } = require('path')
const { env } = require('process')
const { safeLoad } = require('js-yaml')
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

const configPath = resolve('config', 'webpacker.yml')
const loadersDir = join(__dirname, 'loaders')
const settings = safeLoad(readFileSync(configPath), 'utf8')[env.NODE_ENV]

function removeOuterSlashes(string) {
  return string.replace(/^\/*/, '').replace(/\/*$/, '')
}

function formatPublicPath(host = '', path = '') {
  let formattedHost = removeOuterSlashes(host)
  if (formattedHost && !/^http/i.test(formattedHost)) {
    formattedHost = `//${formattedHost}`
  }
  const formattedPath = removeOuterSlashes(path)
  return `${formattedHost}/${formattedPath}/`
}

const output = {
  path: resolve('public', settings.public_output_path),
  publicPath: formatPublicPath(env.ASSET_HOST, settings.public_output_path)
}

module.exports = {
  settings,
  env,
  loadersDir,
  output
}
```

config/webpack/shared.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { basename, dirname, join, relative, resolve } = require('path')
const { sync } = require('glob')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')
const extname = require('path-complete-extname')
const { env, settings, output, loadersDir } = require('./configuration.js')

const extensionGlob = `**/*{${settings.extensions.join(',')}}*`
const entryPath = join(settings.source_path, settings.source_entry_path)
const packPaths = sync(join(entryPath, extensionGlob))

module.exports = {
  entry: packPaths.reduce(
    (map, entry) => {
      const localMap = map
      const namespace = relative(join(entryPath), dirname(entry))
      localMap[join(namespace, basename(entry, extname(entry)))] = resolve(entry)
      return localMap
    }, {}
  ),

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: output.path,
    publicPath: output.publicPath
  },

  module: {
    rules: sync(join(loadersDir, '*.js')).map(loader => require(loader))
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(env))),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name]-[hash].css' : '[name].css'),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      publicPath: output.publicPath,
      writeToFileEmit: true
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: settings.extensions,
    modules: [
      resolve(settings.source_path),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  }
}
```

Comment: Webpacker is not maintained actively. Use the official successor, Shakapacker. If the issue persist, please make a public repo so that one can reproduce and debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try. Though it seems Shakapacker is meant for Webpack 5+. Would you also recommend going from Webpack 4 to 5?

Comment: Updating to shakapacker and webpack 5 did not resolve the issue @MostafaAhangarha

Comment: adding the following seemed to have worked

  "browser": {
    "./src": false,
    "./javascript/application.js": "./javascript/application.js"
  },